# Page refresh under jquery dialog box

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery dialog box that opens a map.  Once the map is closed the page refreshes.  This works correctly.  My question is how can I make it more efficient.  I want the page underneath to refresh and when user selects another link that the dialog box update the information accordingly.  I am using the reload() but some of the resources on the page are very large and take a little bit of time to reload the whole page.

Here is my dialog box:

```
function openBox(v) {
    $("#mapDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 900,
        title: "Deomographic Profile",
        close: function (ev, ui) { window.location.reload() }

    });

    //open dialog and show the legend in the dialog
    $("#mapDiv").dialog("open");
    $("#legend").show();
}//end open box
```

Comment: update only those content which can be changed by dialog operation using ajax request instead of reloading the whole page

Answer (score 0):

You can review your page, decide what parts of it need to be refreshed when the map closes and attach id's to those elements. Then you can call an AJAX method each time the map closes that obtains the information that needs to be refreshed from your server and populates those elements with the information.

Answer (score 0):

Then you might wanna consider using Ajax see doc there: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ It allows you to change some part of the page without refreshing.  If you dont care about internet explorer, you can change the values of the URL without refreshing with these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history giving you the opportunity to have an "history" without really changing page. If you need more help ask me i'll give you some hints

Comment: just tried the window.location.back() i'm not to fond of that for this application.  I do believe the ajax will be the route to go but a point in the right direction is appreciated as i'm new to ajax

Comment: First of all, when you load ajax material, you don't want to reload all your assets (css, js).  So in your php files, whereever you have theses files, add a parameter such as " if (!isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])) { // echo assets }".  Then try with this: http://pastebin.com/gRAgxvgs This might be a little complicated but there's an ajax example ($.POST). You can use all of that script or just take what you need, i dont care